# CRUD/FLS Checks on CronTrigger

Tags: permissions

I've recently had an app fail the security review due to lack of CRUD/FLS checks on dynamic/static SOQL.  These queries against CronTrigger were some of the things flagged:

> 24 Integer count = [SELECT COUNT() FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = :cronName];
>   67 CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = :cronName];

It doesn't appear that there is a way to set CRUD/FLS on CronTrigger.  Is that right?  Is there another way to verify access?  Could this be a false positive?  (I had a meeting with the security team - they didn't note whether it was false or not at that time).

Comment: Hi Dan, You have to add the line for the fields you are using in your query for accessibility check like this:                                                                       if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isAccessible()){
          return '';
// Your Code or query here.
        }
Please reference this Link:  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS

Comment: @AjayDubedi - I've been using that method with other objects for a while.  It didn't work for CronTrigger (although I don't remember the specific issues I had).

Answer (score -1):

You can do CRUD/FLS checks in triggers just like you do them in classes. I think there is some confusion between the sharing keyword, which controls individual record access, and CRUD/FLS, which is about access to the datatype. Triggers cannot be declared 'with sharing' (you'll get a syntax error if you try), but triggers can and should contain the appropriate isAccessible checks needed to comply with your organization's security policy.

Here is some simple example code, if you have an object called `foo__c`, with field `myField__c` in namespace `myns`:

```
trigger permTest on myns__foo__c (before update) {
    Boolean allowAccess = myns__foo__c.myns__myField__c.getDescribe().isUpdateable();

    for (myns__foo__c foo : Trigger.new) {
        if (allowAccess) {
                foo.myns__myField__c = 'You don\'t have permission to change this field';
            } else {
                foo.myns__myField__c = 'You do have permission to change this field';
            }
    }
}
```

You can try creating a user that has sharing access to a specific record and edit access to the object, `myns__foo__c`, but not edit access to the custom field `myns__myField__c`. Then try to modify an object in this user context and verify that the field says you don't have permission to modify it!

This confirms that 1) like all classes, triggers run in system mode, and therefore can modify everything and 2) you can use the same CRUD/FLS checks with objects and fields like everywhere else to ensure that the organization's policies are enforced.

Whether your app needs to respect the organization's security policies doesn't depend on how you implement your code. If you refactor your code to use triggers or batch apex, that doesn't lift the obligation to respect the current security settings. However you are touching data, make sure that you are not overriding any settings made by the org admin. All Apex code has an associated user context -- this includes things like scheduled jobs, batch apex and triggers -- you can use the `getDescribe()` calls to obtain datatype access policies for the associated user context in all of these cases.

Comment: The code is querying CronTrigger directly.  How would an admin set permissions on CronTrigger or any of its fields?

Comment: The code is querying the field permission. The admin sets permission on the field, not on the the trigger. The trigger code needs to respect the admin's permissions on the field.

Comment: How would you set permissions on `CronJobDetail.Name` or `CronTrigger.Id`?

Comment: You must be looking at some different code. myns__foo__c.myns__myField__c.getDescribe().isUpdateable() checks for permissions on myns__foo__c.myns__myField__c.

Comment: Ahh. when you said "the code" in reply to my answer, you meant OP code. :) I gave an example of how to check for CRUD/FLS in triggers.

Comment: Yep ;)  I wrote a class to check access, but I didn't see a way for an admin to even set permissions on cron objects.  That's what the real issue is.

Comment: Yes, this is going to be controlled by profile perms. You can still do the FLS query (similar to doing these queries against custom fields, which are also controlled by profile perms).  I don't think Cronjob is really security relevant, but was showing how to do these queries in a trigger.

Comment: @DanBough The issue descriptions have been updated for these checks to explicitly call them out as false positives. Here is the new description:"This may be a false positive if your code accesses only objects whose security is managed by your app and not the admin (for example OAuth states). It may also be a false positive if checks are performed outside of the dataflow (automatically in a visualforce inputfield tag or manually in a constructor), or if this is an enterprise object or other object whose permissions are not set by the admin."